# How can I build a Dagger-based Android library without forcing consuming applications to use Dagger?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm working on an Android library that is basically a client for some REST services I've written. I have several storage classes, network queues, parsers, and so on, and like many such classes, they have dependencies on `Context` or on things like `SharedPreferences` that are constructed from `Context`. These objects are all hidden behind a facade class, so consumers of my library don't see them or interact with them directly.

For my own sanity, I would like to use Dagger 2 for dependency injection to manage instances of these classes INTERNALLY within my library. However, I don't want to force apps using my library to use Dagger themselves; just because I chose to use Dagger doesn't mean my users should have to.

All the tutorials I've seen seem to expect that I'm building an application, not just a library. Many of these tutorials tell me I should make my `Application` class inherit from `DaggerApplication`. In my case, though, I don't have an `Application` (or any `Activity` or `Service` classes) in my library at all, and I don't want my users to have to use Dagger's base classes.

So how can I use Dagger without "leaking" it out of my library? I've found a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37128723/314890), but I'm not sure how adapt the author's "wrapper" pattern to handle my dependency on `Context`. Can I just pass a context into the wrapper's `getComponent()` method, or will Dagger be able to obtain a Context reference some other way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A library is **almost** like an Application (when it comes to Dagger). Yes, you don’t have an `application` object, but you don’t really need one.

As a *consumer* of your Library, I expect it to be simple to use, so I don’t want to know what dagger is at all (or if you internally use it).

Let your users pass a `Context` when they call your library for the first time (for example). Have a `DaggerInjector` (I think your sample calls it wrapper) that has a static reference to your `Component` interface.

Example (and as such, just a generic example):

```
public class DaggerInjector {

    private static YourComponent component;

    private DaggerInjector() {
        super();
    }

    public static YourComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public static YourComponent buildComponent(Context context) {
        component = DaggerYourComponent
                .builder()
                .yourModule(new YourModule(context))
                .build();
        return component;
    }
}
```

Your “module” can look like:

```
@Module
public class YourModule {

    private Context context;

    public YourModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    final Context providesContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

To use it:

Have your users call a method (or you call it yourself the first time if the component is null):

```
DaggerInjector.buildComponent(context);
```

This will ensure the Dagger component is initialized and the code is generated. Understand that calling `buildComponent` is an expensive task (Dagger has to do a lot!) so only do it once (unless you need to re-initialize the library with different values known at runtime only).

Some libraries simply ask for a context in every call, so that is not out of the question; you could, then, initialize dagger the first time you're called (by checking if getComponent() is null in the injector).

After your `DaggerInjector.getComponent()` is not null anymore, you can now add `@Inject` and the appropriate "injectable" stuff…

e.g.: in `YourModule` you could have:

```
@Provides
SomeObject providesSomeObject() {
    return new SomeObject();
}

// THIS “Context” here is automatically injected by Dagger thanks to the above.
@Provides
@Singleton
SomeOtherObject providesSomeOtherObject(Context context) {
    return new SomeOtherObject(context); //assume this one needs it
}
```

and in any "injectable" object (that is, an object that has an `inject` method in your component…) you can do:

```
public class AnObjectThatWantsToInjectStuff {

    @Inject
    SomeObject someObject;
    @Inject 
    SomeOtherObject someOtherObject;

    public AnObjectThatWantsToInjectStuff() {
          super();
          DaggerInjector.getComponent().inject(this);

          // you can now use someObject and someOtherObject
    }
}
```

For the above to work, you need in `YourComponent` (which is an Interface) code like this:

`void inject(AnObjectThatWantsToInjectStuff object);`

(otherwise calling `DaggerInjector.getComponent().inject(this)` will fail at compile time)

Notice I never passed a context to `YourInjectableContext`, Dagger already knows how to obtain it.

Be careful with leaks tho. I recommend that you store `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of just plain `Context` for all/most cases (unless you explicitly need an Activity context for inflating layouts/theme purposes, the application context supplied by the consuming application is all you need).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I've followed your suggestions, and everything is working well.

Comment: Is it working anyone? Followed the same process but not working. I am getting “cannot find symbol class DaggerYourComponent” error while building the app. @Dalbergia, Is it working without UI component of android?

Comment: It does work for me and apparently the OP also made it work. @TejasMehta try clean/rebuild or something. Your error means your component wasn’t properly generated or you’re not using the correct name.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMarconcini After multiple clean/rebuild solved the issue. Its working now.

Comment: @TejasMehta, yes, MartinMarconcini 's answer was correct, as you found. "DaggerYourComponent" is an implementation of the "YourComponent" interface, generated by Dagger as part of the build process, so you have to force a build to happen before the class willo be recognized.

Comment: How does this work with DaggerAppCompatActivity? I get errors surrounding the injectors.

Comment: How to achieve this in case I have created a component and my library uses different modules..?

Comment: @Himanshu I don't fully understand what you mean by _uses different modules_, Dagger is a complicated program, it can do a lot, and it can be very confusing; I suggest you post a concrete question to get a better answer.

Comment: @VikashParajuli Sure, [here's the official Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) about using Android/Hilt. Very easy to follow and you should have it up and running in 10 minutes.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini My typing mistake I want to create an android library without Activity and Fragment. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @VikashParajuli I haven't had the need to do or try this. So I cannot help you with that. You can, however [search and find other people](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2132) trying to do the same. Perhaps you will find your answer there.